# Angular UI Bootstrap collapse - whats wrong?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-bootstrap

I can't seem to get angular ui bootstraps collapse directive to work. I've set up a plunkr with a minimal example, but its still non functional. Anyone shed any light on this?

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/gwy2CTw6h4PIGUgy39fd?p=preview)

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.1.*" data-semver="3.3.1" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.7" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.7/angular.js"></script>
    <script data-require="ui-bootstrap@*" data-semver="0.12.0" src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.0.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="CollapseController">
    <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="collapsed = !collapsed">Toggle</button>
    <div collapse="collapsed">
      <div>
        <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

JS

```
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('CollapseController', function($scope){
  $scope.collapsed = false;
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should declare a dependency in your app module on `ui.bootstrap` module:

```
angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']);
```

Here's your updated working [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/lwd2CTzLZLj9ssNuRBGn?p=preview).

Comment: @SimonTrewhella it happens with all of us sometimes :)

Answer (score 5):

You need to declare `ui.bootstrap` module dependency in order to use it:

```
angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap'])
```